# Why is it hard to shift gears?

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, opel

Why is my transmission extremely stiff and resistant to changing gears when I drive?

I drive an Opel Combo C manual. While driving through the mountains, and lots of engine braking, I noticed a smell of burning rubber coming from under the hood. I looked and there was steam coming out of what looks like the transmission. I started driving again and suddenly shifting gears became very hard and sometimes it makes a scratchy noise.

[image]

Did engine braking damage my transmission?

And what can I do to investigate the shifting problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Difficult shifts in manual xmissions may be one of several issues; well worn clutch, damaged clutch pedal linkages, loss of hydraulic oil or if non hydraulic - periodic adjustment of clutch pedal linkages as clutch wears.

Comment: Since it only happens when shifting, I would guess a worn-out clutch.  The clutch *should not* be slipping while engine braking, but if it *was* splipping (e.g. because someone was foolishly pressing the clutch pedal), it would quickly use up remaining clutch life.   Fortunately, clutches are consumables and clutch change is an occasional maintenance repair like lead-acid battery, or brakes.  Skill is a huge factor in clutch life.